# Calculus Differentiable Functions, Limits

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Regarding this question:

Let $f$ be a function that is defined on a neighborhood of $0$.

Suppose that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} = 1$. Then $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

--

So I think this is true, and I want to separate it to 3 options $f(0)=0$, $f(0)<0$, $f(0)>0$:

If $f(0)=0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$

From here, I want to separate it to $0^+$ and $0^-$, so:

$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ and from the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} = 1$, I can say that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$.

$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x)}{-x}$ and from the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{|x|} = 1$, I can say that $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x)}{x} = -1$.

Is that legit? I'm not sure if I can say that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think that's valid. All you've done is rewrite the function using its definition on the side you're approaching from, and then using linearity, so I don't see how it could cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you!!! :D

Comment: I have edited your questiong, removing from it the [tag:proof-writing] tag, which is not appropriate for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved correctly that $\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)}x=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)}x=-1$; so $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x=$ doesn't exist.

Note that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{|x|}=1\implies\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ (since $\lim_{x\to0}|x|=0$). so, there are now two possibilities: either $f(0)\ne0$ or $f(0)=0$. In the first case, $f$ isn't even continuous at $0$, and therefore it cannot be differentiable there. Otherwise, what was done above shows that the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x$ doesn't exist, and so, again, $f$ cannot be differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: Edit: If for some function $g$ such that it isn't continuous at $0$, $g$ can be differentiable there, so I disagree with the second part of your comment about $f$...

Comment: You are wrong. But, if you believe in what you wrote, then please provide an example of such a function.

Comment: In the definition of differentiable, a function is differentiable if the limit $\lim_{x \to x_{0}}=\frac{f(x)-f(x_{0}}{x-x-{0}}$ exists. There is no mention about continuity...

Comment: Ohh but if a function is differentiable so it must be continuous, so what you are saying is basically the contra-positive of that?

Comment: If the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ is some number $l$, then$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}(x-x_0)\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=0\times l=0$$and therefore, $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$. So, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. But, again, please provide an example of such a function.

Comment: Yes. Since differentiable $\implies $ continuous, non continuous $\implies $ non differentiable.

Comment: You are definitely right, I am so sorry for that. Again - thank you so much! I really appreciate that! :)